# How can i remove bullet from dragable element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Remove listing bullets from the draggable element . when the element is dragged it is dragging it with the bullet so how can i remove that bullet.
    here you can check my code - `*http://jsfiddle.net/aNreg/197*`
i want to remove the bullet when i am dragging the element and also after dropping element.

Comment: also provide your code here

Comment: In jquery `$('.button-orange').parent().css('list-style-type','none');` In css `list-style-type:none'` http://jsfiddle.net/krish/aNreg/202/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aNreg/197

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the rule

```
li.ui-draggable-dragging {
    list-style:none;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/E8SmW/)

The problem is since the draggable item is cloned the existing rule is not applied to it

Answer (score 0):

Your css is too restrictive. If you use

```
li.third
```

instead of

```
.ui-widget-content ul li
```

that will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Make the list style type none to your draggable element. like this

`list-style:none;`